# javascript or jquery opening lightbox image through ajax sending post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, colorbox

I'm struggling in putting together Ajax post request with any light box.
Concept is that clicking a link a post request is sent to server with data containing image identifier and some sort of user validation info.
Resulting jpg image should be shown in a responsive open source light box.
Tried lightboxj.js and magic box without success.
Is it possible? 
Any example? Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I'm including now some code which does half of the job: it load into a specific div (#imageHidden) the image I need (so the "POST" request is covered)

```
$("#testa").bind('click', function(e){
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    data       : {
     username:   username,
     password:   password,
     img:        img
    },
    url: php_url, 
    success: function(data){ //read the value and save in settings
    if (data.length>0) {
                $('#hiddenImage').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data + '" />'); 
                // $.colorbox({href:"#hiddenImage"});       
    }
  });
```

I would then set this div as hidden to avoid showing it on the page (I want it to be shown in the lightbox only)...

Now the problem is how to show this into a lightbox. Any suggestion?

For some reason colorbox is not working in my case

Thanks

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, some of sorted:

1. colorbox needs the attribute inline to be true to show content of the page:

   ```
   $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#hiddenImage"});
   ```
2. I've put my #hiddenImage into an #hiddenDiv:

   ```
   #hiddenDiv {     display: none; }
   ```

**UPDATE 3**

Ok,I think it works now.
I used colorbox as my lightbox.
Note that #hiddenImage is the image a want to show which will be loaded inside an invisible (display:none) #hiddenDiv DIV.

For everyone interested the final code is:

```
   $("#testa").bind('click', function(e){
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({ 
type: "POST",
data       : {
 username:   username,
 password:   password,
 img:        img
},
url: php_url, 
success: function(data){ //read the value and save in settings
if (data.length>0) {
            $('#hiddenImage').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data + '" />'); 
            $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#hiddenImage"});
}
 });
 });
```

Only remaining issue seems that sometime the lightbos is empty but this gets solved if I set a timer to wait few tenths of sec before calling colorbox.

Is there a way to ensure the code

```
   $('#hiddenImage').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data + '" />');
```

is fully executed before calling colorbox (apart the ugly settimeout option) ?

Comment: Can you provide code (a fiddle) and more details about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got right also the lightbox show only after img is fully loaded:

HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenDiv"><img src="" id="hiddenImg"/></div><a href="#" id="testa">Click Here</a>
```

CSS:

```
#hiddenDiv {     display: none; }
```

JS:

```
 $("#testa").bind('click', function(e){
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({ 
type: "POST",
data       : {
username:   username,
password:   password,
img:        img
},
url: php_url, 
success: function(data){ //read the value and save in settings
if (data.length>0) {
        $('#hiddenImage').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data + '" />'); 
        $("#hiddenImage").load(function() {
             $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#hiddenImage"});
        });
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is a little messy, but the gist of how you'd do this is there.

With [Lokesh Dhakar's lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), you can change the `href` of a lightboxified `a` element after page load. By updating it from a callback of an ajax call, you can set it to be an image url returned by that ajax call.

```js
var ajaxDummyJpg = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';

function fireAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '#',
    complete: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      // Replace this with actual returned image url and use success instead
      $('a').attr('href', ajaxDummyJpg);
      $('a').text('This will now point to ' + ajaxDummyJpg);
    }
  });
}

$('#fireAjax').on('click', fireAjax);
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/src/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rawgit.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/src/css/lightbox.css"/>

<button id="fireAjax">Fill Image</button>

<a href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox">This will be blank currently.</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but the point is not changing on the fly the link. I need the whole image to be served as data_Uri or other proper image header. The image can be served only upon providing though Ajax request img ref username and password with post...

Comment: I see your problem. Try setting the link to be the url of the ajax call, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866447/how-to-assign-ajax-response-image-stream-to-the-image-control